# have problem in stacked group bar graph javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, laravel

I have problem in my javascript. [This is my bar graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nyVy.png)

i have 3 bar in one month. each bar have 3 status of every candidate. i have three year of average from my bar graph.

i want just [three of this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPBrx.png) from my bar graph. And remove duplicate content to get a better bar graph in my project.
this is my code.

```js
new Chart(document.getElementById("MyChart"), {
                type: 'bar',
                data: {
                    labels: [2017, 2018, 2019],
                    datasets: [{
                    label: "Gagal",
                    type: "bar",
                    stack: "Base",
                    backgroundColor: "red",
                    data: [30, 31, 32],
                    }, {
                    label: "Menunggu",
                    type: "bar",
                    stack: "Base",
                    backgroundColor: "yellow",
                    data: [15, 16, 17],
                    },{
                    label: "Lulus",
                    type: "bar",
                    stack: "Base",
                    backgroundColor: "green",
                    data: [15, 16, 17],
                    }, {
                    label: "Gagal",
                    type: "bar",
                    stack: "Sensitivity",
                    backgroundColor: "red",
                    data: [20, 21, 22],
                    }, {
                    label: "Menunggu",
                    type: "bar",
                    stack: "Sensitivity",
                    backgroundColor: "yellow",
                    backgroundColorHover: "yellow",
                    data: [10, 11, 12]
                    },{
                    label: "Lulus",
                    type: "bar",
                    stack: "Sensitivity",
                    backgroundColor: "green",
                    backgroundColorHover: "green",
                    data: [10, 11, 12]
                    },
                    {
                    label: "Gagal",
                    type: "bar",
                    stack: "Kehormat",
                    backgroundColor: "red",
                    data: [20, 21, 22],
                    }, {
                    label: "Menunggu",
                    type: "bar",
                    stack: "Kehormat",
                    backgroundColor: "yellow",
                    backgroundColorHover: "yellow",
                    data: [10, 11, 12]
                    }, {
                    label: "Lulus",
                    type: "bar",
                    stack: "Kehormat",
                    backgroundColor: "green",
                    backgroundColorHover: "green",
                    data: [10, 11, 12]
                    }]
                },
                options: {
                    scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        //stacked: true,
                        stacked: true,
                        ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true,
                        maxRotation: 0,
                        minRotation: 0
                        }
                    }],
                    yAxes: [{
                        stacked: true,
                    }]
                    },
                }
                });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.min.js"></script>
            <canvas id="MyChart" width="400" height="200" ></canvas>
```

i want make stacked group bar graph for my company. please help me.